# -ms-transform not working with IE 11

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer-11, internet-explorer-10

Adding `-ms-transform:rotate(90deg)` dynamically using jQuery to the element. But, its not working in IE 11. However, `-webkit-transform:rotate(90deg)` is working in Chrome.

No transformation is happening on page.

Added meta :

```
<meta http-equiv=X-UA-Compatible content="IE=9;IE=10;IE=11;IE=Edge,chrome=1">
```

[image]

Comment: which version of IE does it not work in? I believe that should work on IE9 or later. If you're using IE8, there's an answer here which might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11900870/rotating-a-text-to-270-degrees-in-ie8

Comment: According to IE css transformations are supported after IE9. I'm using IE11.

Comment: Do you also have the `transform` property? Prefixes are phased out when the browser gets full support of the feature.

Comment: @Juhana  yes.. Check the image ... Added now.

Comment: What is your jQuery version?

Comment: @thepio 1.7.2. Jquery is doing its wrok, and code is working fine on mozilla and chrome.

Comment: Can you try to bump up your jQuery version to atleas 2.x.x and see if it helps.

Comment: @thepio   I will try.. But, on adding `-ms-transform:rotate(90deg)` manually to the element is also not working. So, i think there is some issue with IE itself.

Comment: You do not need the `-ms-` prefix for IE11. Just use `transform: rotate(90deg)`

Comment: @thepio check the image. IE seems to be avoiding `transfrom` and using `-ms-transfrom`

Comment: But how about manually adding **ONLY** the transform without the prefix?

Comment: @thepio, yeah cascading effect probably the real cause here. I'm starting to think OP didn't try just the one.

Comment: @thepio Pretty interesting, this works. Then how will one can use this with JS

Comment: @Chris yeah it's hard to tell what really has been tried out and what has not.

Comment: @atulquest93, probably just `$("#yourElement").css("transform", "rotate(90deg)");`

Comment: I also undeleted my previous answer and modified it a bit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on the comments on your question you could then check the IE version with something like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/jquerybyexample/gk7xA/

And insert the `transform` property with or without the prefix `-ms-` according to this checkup. The example above is just pure JavaScript because:

> The jQuery.browser() method has been deprecated since jQuery 1.3 and is removed in 1.9. **If needed, it is available as part of the jQuery Migrate plugin. We recommend using feature detection with a library such as Modernizr.**

**EDIT:**

And actually you said you are using jQuery 1.7.2 so you could use the jQuery method to detect the browser and version.

Documentation: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.browser/